# object in category isomorphic to initial object need not be initial

Tags: category-theory

I saw in Wikipedia "Initial and terminal objects" that an object in a category which is isomorphic to an initial object, must be an initial object itself. I can't prove it, and I think I have a simple counter example. Can anybody help me decide whether there is an error in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: This is 100% true.

Comment: Yes, we can help you, we'll be able to help you a lot more if you show us your example.

Comment: Here is the counter example. I have to describe it in words. There are three vertices, I,J,C. There is an arrow f from I to C and an arrow x from I to J. There are two arrows from J to I, y and z. zx and yx are identity on I, and xy and xz are identity on J. So I is initial, J isomorphic to I but not initial.

Comment: why can't they? Please explain.

Comment: Also, can't we prove that $y=z$ so that $J$ is in fact initial?  Either that, or this doesn't give a category to begin with.

Comment: Yes, you've said $zx=1$ and $xz=1$, so $z=x^{-1}$. But you also said $yx=1$ and $xy=1$, so $y=x^{-1}$.  Thus $y=z$.  $J$ is still initial and this isn't a problem.

Comment: This is a category, not a group. Why can't there be two inverses?

Comment: Inverses of isos are unique in a category.  It's even the same proof.

Comment: $y = y \circ 1_J = y \circ (x \circ z) = (y \circ x) \circ z = 1_I \circ z =z$

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem.....